# Three unique values of mysql table

Tags: mysql

Consider I have **three** fields in a mysql table.

- field1
- field2
- field3

I know that if I join field1 and field2 as unique the following rules apply:

`field1, field2
   1       2   //is allowed
   2       1   //is NOT allowed if (1,2) exists`

My doubt is how this would work with three fields. For example

`field1, field2, field3
   1       2       1    //is allowed
   1       2       2    //is this allowed (if previous exist)?
   2       1       2    //is this allowed? (if previous exist)
   2       1       3    //is this allowed? (only if the first one exists)`

What I'd really need is to avoid the repetition of **field1 and field2 pairs**. This is, I would like `1 2 1` to exist as well as `1 2 2` but `2 1 1` or `2 1 2` should not exist (notice the field1 and field2 switch). How exactly does this work?

Comment: One idea is to consider the opposite logic: Always store both versions, but with a flag that indicates which version is 'real'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the column values before INSERTing.  That way, field1 is always < field2 and field2 < field3.  When you about to INSERT, also sort.  Then you could have `UNIQUE(field1, field2, field3) as a constraint to prevent dups.

Answer (score -1):

really i dont know what you doing, but note when you put a unique field, that cant repeat, so no problem for, `0 0 0 0 , 1 1 1 1, 2 2 2 2, 3 3 3 3`, but if you trying make a numbers followed `1 0 0 1, 1 0 0 2...` you result is error, and the data will not be saved. becouse field1 repeat with "1", maybe you can put what you doing, for give other option, becouse with this configuration you can store a limited data

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say

Comment: Correct. I cannot understand nothing.